# Doesn't closing a question just abandon it to the void?

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions

It has happened a couple of times that I ask a question, and because I'm not a great copy-writer, it's not well formulated or it's too complex or too broad.

Then what happens is that several people close the question and it goes into limbo.

Plus to make matters worse, the question gets downvoted at -2 points a vote.

There appears to be some sort of half-closed state for a while, before being finally marked closed.

Following the suggestions, I edit the question to try to make it clearer and I leave comments to try to engage dialog with the people who downvoted or closed the question. However it seems none of this is seen or read by anybody.

When someone has made a comment, I can add their name with an @-sign and the name pops up in an auto-complete box. When I type the @-sign and someone's name who closed the question, it doesn't auto-complete so I wonder whether they are notified that I am trying to attract their attention.

I voted for the question to be re-opened but it tells me it needs 5 votes which seems an impossible ask.

So what do I do to save the question? Or shall I abandon it and re-ask with a new question?

[Closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25691251/java-method-to-generalise-string-manipulation-with-an-input-string-command-param)

Comment: The close reason is a perfect fit IMHO. You're asking for a library or off-site resource. If you really want to rescue that question you could try to add some code that demonstrates what you want to achieve/ where you are stuck. The possible answers either fix your attempt or suggest a library.

Comment: I haven't looked at your specific question yet. Editing puts it back into a reopen queue but, yes, practically speaking even if all original issues were fixed questions don't always end up getting reopened in my experience.

Comment: Looks no longer unclear, but instead like a request for an offline resource. Re-opening just to re-close would be a waste of time.

Comment: You can't [contact close voters](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/158100) but there are a couple of [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56849/notify-close-voters-when-a-closed-question-gets-edited) that ask for that...

Comment: I guess I could answer add code to the question, I suppose it can't do any harm in any case. @Deduplicator - I didn't know about any re-open queue. That's probably why it appeared to gain more Close votes even after it was closed, is it, because I edited it and it was still below spec?

Comment: It can't gain closed votes when closed. The move from "on hold" to closed is purely time based.

Comment: I just edited that question and it almost immediately got an anonymous down-vote, even though it remained closed. So presumably it is still searchable, someone found it and didn't like it? Or was it someone looking at it on the "re-open" queue? BTW where is the re-open queue? Can you only see it once you have a certain number of points?

Comment: The reopen queue is here http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/ I'm not sure what you will see. You might also be receiving downvotes due to the [meta effect](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect)

Comment: Hopefully the meta effect will only be mild! Very interesting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I voted for the question to be re-opened but it tells me it needs 5 votes which seems an impossible ask

When you edit your post after closing it will appear in the "Reopen votes" [review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review) where people will be asked to vote for or against re-opening. You don't have to find those people yourself. So no, your question does not get totally abandoned.

Comment: It was closed a month ago, but despite me trying to edit it well, nobody is voting for it to be re-opened (well, maybe 1 or 2 max, but not 5). Because there are also no more comments, I think it's just lack of interest. Frustratingly the 're-open' link no longer shows how many votes it has or needs. Am I missing something? Do I need to edit the question more? There's no way of knowing that I can see.